# Execution time in Python regarding classes and assigning values

Tags: python, class, execution-time

I tried methods on how different ways of changing variable values and came upon something which I did not expect. I would have thought that changing the value itself, instead of assigning a new class to a variable would be faster. Can someone explain to me why A is faster than B?

```
from time import time

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.a + other

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.a)

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 0

    def __add__(self, other):
        self.b += other

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.b)


a = A()
b = B()

s =  time()
for _ in range(10**6):
    a = a + 1
print(a, time()-s, " seconds")

s =  time()
for _ in range(10**6):
    b + 1
print(b, time()-s, " seconds")
```

Output:

```
1000000 0.12671232223510742  seconds
1000000 0.2434854507446289  seconds
```

EDIT: Added code.

```
s =  time()
for i in range(10**6):
    a = a + i
print(a, time()-s, " seconds")

s =  time()
for i in range(10**6):
    b + i
print(b, time()-s, " seconds")
```

Output:

```
499999500000 0.15620923042297363  seconds
499999500000 0.2812356948852539  seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure your code runs as you've intented it to. Method `A._add_` is called only once with argument integer 1. After this 1 is assigned to variable `a` and from this moment only integers are being added in the loop.

If we change the code so the method is called in every iteration, we'll get almost identical time.

```
s =  time()
acc = 0
for _ in range(10**6):
    acc += a + 1
print(acc, time()-s, " seconds")

s =  time()
for _ in range(10**6):
    b + 1
print(b, time()-s, " seconds")
```

Result:

```
1000000 0.14543867111206055  seconds
1000000 0.14631319046020508  seconds
```

Comment: I don't follow what you mean with `A._add_` being called only once and then integers being added to the loop. I think it works as I intended, for example changing the code to the addition I made in the original post gives me the result I was expecting.
EDIT: Yeah, now I get it. Thanks!